# Transmitting an exe file via network in Qt

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, network-programming, qfile

I am trying to create a Remote compiling system in Qt. What I am trying to do is to get the C/C++ source from the client and calling the locally available GCC via QProcess on the server, create the exe file and then transmit the exe back to the client. Simple right?

The exe file is being generated perfectly but Qt is just not able to read the file into an array to transmit it.

My Code is:

```
QByteArray arr;
qDebug() << "To Client: exe";
QFile f("compiled.exe");
qDebug() << f.exists(); //output = false
QString path = QDir::toNativeSeparators(QFileInfo(f).absoluteFilePath()); 
qDebug() << path; //perfect path is coming
qDebug() << f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); //output = flase
arr = f.readAll(); // size of arr is 0
f1.close();
client->write(arr); //zero bytes written
```

Although the exe file is very much present, I am getting such outputs. I tried with other files in the same directory, it works absolutely perfectly. Only exe files wont work.
I am using Qt 4.8.1 32 bit on Windows using MSVC v16.00.40219.10 as the compiler.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Did you check the output from `QIODevice::errorString()` ?

Comment: Maybe the file is in use ? Did u close the QProcess instance ?

Comment: Try opening the file with `::open` or `::fopen` C library function, then check function's return value, global variable `errno` and C string returned by `strerror(errno)`. That way you get more exact error message... At least on Unix, not 100% sure about Windows/mingw...

Answer (score 1):

No need to speculate, there is a [description of error codes](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfile.html#FileError-enum) when using `QFile::open()`. 
Btw

```
qDebug() << f.exists(); //output = false
```

It seems `compiled.exe` is not in the process working directory, neither nor in any direcotry in path. Provide the complete path...